# Capstone Disassembly Engine Issue: OP_Access throws TypeError

Tags: disassembly, windows, dynamic-analysis, python, disassemblers

After installing the Capstone python module, I ran this [example](http://www.capstone-engine.org/op_access.html) on a Win7x86 PC with a *minor edit* (added arch and mode).

However, when attempting to use `insn.regs_access()`, it throws a `NoneType` object which is not iterable:

```
enter preformatted text here

  1 from capstone import *
  2
  3 CODE = b"\x8d\x4c\x32\x08\x01\xd8"
  4
  5 md = Cs(CS_ARCH_X86, CS_MODE_32)
  6 md.detail = True
  7
  8 for insn in md.disasm(code, 0x1000):
  9     print("%s\t%s" % (insn.mnemonic, insn.op_str))
 10
 11     (regs_read, regs_write) = insn.regs_access()
 12
 13     if len(regs_read) > 0:
 14         print("\n\tRegisters read:", end="")
 15         for r in regs_read:
 16             print(" %s" %(insn.reg_name(r)))
 17         
 18
 19     if len(regs_write) > 0:
 20         print("\n\tRegisters modified:")
 21         for r in regs_write:
 22             print(" %s" %(insn.reg_name(r)))
```

However, I get the following:

```
X:\blah>python capTest.py
lea    ecx, dword ptr [edx + esi + 8]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "capTest.py", line 11, in <module>
   (regs_read, regs_write) = insn.regs_access()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emailed Quynh, a member of the Capstone team. He was more than helpful!

Compiled from next branch in msvc...msvc2012 is a prereq. works now!

if you try to build with cygwin you'll receive an error in cs_open (exported by cs.c)